# Is it possible to run an IPA file in an iPhone simulator on Windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, simulator, ipa

If so, what programs or SDK do I need?

Answer (score 3):

NO.  The SDK and tool chain (including simulator) are for OS X only.

Comment: Also, the binaries in the .ipa compressed bundle are compiled for the ARM architecture of the iOS devices and wouldn't run on Intel-based systems anyway.

Comment: In addition, the ARM executable code in ipa bundles from the App store may be encrypted.  So even an ARM CPU emulator, if one for iOS devices even existed, wouldn't help.