# I have a .ipa (iphone application file). Can we built iPhone simulator for Windows OS and test the application?

Tags: iphone

i am newbie to iphone testing..

Development team has given .ipa files to our team.

Is there any way to test the application by building simulator (in Windows OS)? If yes, please let me know the way.

If there is no way, atleast it would be can we sync or download this ipa files in device any where iphones and test it?

Please let me know which is the best way...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run an IPA file in an iPhone simulator on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585076/is-it-possible-to-run-an-ipa-file-in-an-iphone-simulator-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can get .ipa onto the device using iTunes for Windows.  And no, you cannot build a simulator to run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can only sync it to your device if your device is allowed to run the app, i.e. if it was code signed properly.