# iPhone emulator for Windows that allows installation of new apps

Tags: iphone, installation, emulation

In my work I need to perform some tests on iOS iPhone, and for that I need an emulator for the iPhone.

The problem is that this emulator should allow the installation of new applications, but among those who have researched (e.g MobiOne), there is this installation option.

Anyone know of a program with such functionality?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows for this task, and I have an application that a client must be installed on this emulator.

Then these constraints are:
An emulator that works on Windows and allows the installation of this application.

Comment: There is no full iOS simulator for Windows. Even the iOS simulator for mac can only do so much. You will need a real device for debugging and testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run an IPA file in an iPhone simulator on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585076/is-it-possible-to-run-an-ipa-file-in-an-iphone-simulator-on-windows)

Comment: Not possible, because Apple are a bunch of monopolistic *****.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There exists no iOS device emulator that runs on Windows, or on anything else (outside of maybe Apple R&D).  The iOS Simulator only runs on Intel Macs running OS X 10.6.x (or newer), as the simulation environment pretty much requires an entire Mac OS X installation to run.  And the iOS Simulator only runs apps compiled for x86 anyway, not ARM apps.

The only way to test an App store app for an iPhone is on actual Apple iOS hardware.

Comment: You also can't install anything on the simulator unless it's built from the source using Xcode or loaded through Safari.

Comment: @ing0 : Not true.  You can now copy compiled x86 .app bundles from an iOS Simulator on another Mac directly into your Simulator support directory and run them, without source.

Comment: I didn't know that, although I'm assuming you cannot run a .app taken from your iPhone though, right?

Comment: @hotpaw2 : It is 2016 now. Is the "iPadian - The iOS Simulator For Windows" one such free emulator ? Or is  that a scam?

Answer (score 3):

An iPhone emulator/simulator is part of the iOS SDK. Note that it does not support simulating the built-in hardware sensors such as GPS, the Accelerometer, Gyro, Camera etc.

See the [official docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html) You can download it from the [DevCenter](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention some details. Please see the edit I made in my topic. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Apple's Platform lock-in politics, but seriously, get a Mac for doing iOs Development. Else, use something like MonoTouch.

Comment: You will still need a mac for testing when using MonoTouch

Comment: I see that I do not have many options so I'll appeal to some of these.
Thanks to all!!

Comment: Nope, it is not an emulator that for example allows installation of stuff from the app store. Xcode IDE / SDK only contains a simulator running your own non yet iOS compiled stuff

Answer (score 1):

There is no iOS simulator for Windows.  Furthermore, even on the actual iOS Simulator you cannot install third-party applications to test, because the Simulator runs a different architecture than actual iOS devices do (ARM).

Answer (score -1):

An iPhone emulator comes with Delphi XE5 that currently is able to compile native iOS application without XCode.

It seems that Delphi XE5 use a ARM toolchain for create cross binary executables for iOS.

See the iPhone emulator at work in the following video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Afvai7q2Uqk

Comment: Nope that's not an emulator, just a simulator for ones own apps. Not working with AppStore apps